# How to check with server before writing to Firebase database when offline?

Tags: swift, firebase

Before I write to the Firebase database, I'd like to check if the write is valid via a Firebase function. When a user is online this is easy because I can put the Firebase database write in a completion callback which is fired after the server function returns. However, I'm not sure how to handle the offline case:

Since the server can't be reached offline, then the completion handler will never return and data will not be written to the Firebase database cache. However, if I bypass the server check when offline, when reconnected, the Firebase cache will sync and write possibly corrupt data to the Database (if the server would have caught it when online).

Here is an example:

```
checkWithServerIfDataIsSanitzied(data) { sanitized in
   if sanitized {
     // The problem is that this won't write to firebase if
     // The user is offline since there is no connection to server.
     writeToFirebaseDatabase(data) 
   }
}
```

What is the standard practice to write data offline when server code is required to validate?

Thanks

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you're doing. A lot here depends on your platform, and how you actually implement the functionality. Can you edit your question to show the minimal code that reproduces the problem that you're asking about. It'll be much more likely that we'll be able to understand if we can see the code that reproduces the problem.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I gave a sudo example of what my code does now. The problem is that this won't write to firebase if offline. However I don't want to write corrupt data. Essentially, I want to let the user write to the cache until the connection is established to check with the server if the data can be added to the database.

Comment: Why don't you use security rules to validate the data? That ensures it gets validated on the server, without you have to jump through hoops. Alternatively, you can post to the database from within your Cloud Functions code, which means everything happens in a single call from the client (but also won't work when the client is offline).

Comment: While data will not be written to the server when the user is offline, if [Persistence](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/offline-capabilities) is enabled then once the user goes back online, it will be sync'd. So that part of your question is confusing.